# C++ Design: Overloading/Overriding many many functions, way to clean up?

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, overriding

The case I am trying to implement here is a Base class which has a function (let's call it modify_command) which can accept many different types virtually so derived classes can implement the modify_command function as they see fit. 
Right now I have something along these lines in the base class:

```
class Base 
{
    template<typename Command>
    void modify_command(Command cmd)
    { 
        std::cout << "Modify command called with unimplemented command type:" << typeid(cmd).name();
    }

    virtual void modify_command(SpecificCommandA cmd)
    {
         modify_command<SpecificCommandA>(cmd); // Calls the templated function
    }

    virtual void modify_command(SpecificCommandB cmd)
    {
         modify_command<SpecificCommandB>(cmd); // Calls the templated function
    }

    // etc.
};
```

Then in a derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void modify_command(SpecificCommandA cmd)
    {
        cmd.x = 1;
        cmd.y = 2;
    }
}
```

Obviously a virtual template function isn't a possibility so in some form I am going to have to list function declarations for umpteen many argument possibilities which is sure to clutter the class definition and may make it difficult (over time) for additional command types to be handled

The purpose of having the templated function is for this case to compile without needing definition of modify_command(SpecificCommandC) to log an error:

```
Base * base = new Derived();
SpecificCommandA a;
SpecificCommandB b;
SpecificCommandC c;
base->modify_command(a); //Set's x and y
base->modify_command(b); //Outputs that command type is unimplemented
base->modify_command(c); //Outputs that command type is unimplemented
```

I really hate how I have this working, does anyone have a suggestion on how this can be cleaned up / reimplemented? The number of commands will continue to grow as the software matures, so extensibility is a must.

Edit: Grammar

Comment: Create a SpecificCommand base class with a member function, e.g. onModifyCommand, which modify_command calls.

Comment: @kfsone I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Each one of my derived classes will modify the command differently (sometimes not at all). How would that give my Derivations the ability to specify it's own implementation for modifying the command?

Comment: It seems you want the equivalent of a virtual template function without having to declare all of the specific overloads in the derived classes as virtual functions in the base class.  Please confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what would solve your problem is a virtual template method, that is not possible.

Here is a more *C-ish* solution brought to the C++ world that can work around the limitation:

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<functional>
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

struct BaseCommand {
    static int counter;
};

int BaseCommand::counter = 0;

template<class T>
struct Command: BaseCommand {
    static int type() {
        static const int t = ++counter;
        return t;
    }
};

struct SpecificCommand1: Command<SpecificCommand1> {};
struct SpecificCommand2: Command<SpecificCommand2> {};

class Base {
    struct Handler {
        virtual void operator()(BaseCommand &cmd) = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct THandler: Handler {
        std::function<void(T)> func;
        void operator()(BaseCommand &cmd) override {
            func(static_cast<T&>(cmd));
        }
    };
protected:
    template<typename T>
    void assign(std::function<void(T)> f) {
        auto handler = std::make_unique<THandler<T>>();
        handler->func = f;
        handlers[T::type()] = std::move(handler);
    }

public:
    template<typename Command>
    void modifyCommand(Command cmd) {
        auto it = handlers.find(Command::type());
        if(it == handlers.end()) {
            std::cout << "Modify command called with unimplemented command type: " << Command::type();
        } else {
            auto &h = *(it->second);
            h(cmd);
        }
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Handler>> handlers;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::function<void(SpecificCommand1)> f =
            [](SpecificCommand1) {
                std::cout << "handler for SpecificCommand1" << std::endl;
            };

        assign(f);
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *b = new Derived;
    b->modifyCommand(SpecificCommand1{});
    b->modifyCommand(SpecificCommand2{});
}
```

The basic idea is to give a numeric type at runtime to your commands (it can be done with the CRTP idiom - see `BaseCommand` and the `Command` template class).
With this value accessible, it's a matter of creating a *type-erased* handler to deal with the commands for which you want to provide a specific implementation (see `assign` and `Handler`/`THandler`).
Once you have all the pieces correctly set, you have only to design and initialize those handlers in your derived classes. For it can be done using `std::function`, you can use as an handler a lambda, a public or private member method, a static method and so on.
See the constructor of `Derived` for further details.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think a map of handlers might be the best way to do this with out 30+ declarations, +1

Comment: Decided to take your example and fudged it a bit to better fit my needs, there was some info I left out in the question that is proprietary which easily produces keys for this usage. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but I am going ahead with what I have come up with:

A small metaprogram to find a type within a typelist/variadic param list. Needed to identify whether a command is part of implementation or not.

```
namespace meta {
template <typename... T> struct list{};
template <typename F, typename T> struct has_type;

template <typename F>
struct has_type<F, list<>> {
  using type = typename std::false_type;
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename F, typename... T>
struct has_type<F, list<F, T...>> {
  using type = typename std::true_type;
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename F, typename H, typename... T>
struct has_type<F, list<H,T...>> {
  using type = typename std::false_type;
  static constexpr bool value =
    std::is_same<F, typename std::decay<H>::type>::value ? true : has_type<F, list<T...>>::value;
};
}
```

Now Define your commands having a common base class:

```
struct CommandBase {};

struct CommandA: CommandBase {};
struct CommandB: CommandBase {};
struct SomeCommandType: CommandBase {};
struct CommandC: CommandBase {};

using AvailableCommmands = meta::list<CommandA, CommandB, SomeCommandType>;
```

The `AvailableCommmands` type decides for what type `not implemented` message should come. If a particular coomand type is not present in `AvailableCommmands` meta::list, then for that type `not implemeneted` message should be printed.

Rest of the code (base + derived):

```
class Base
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  void on_modify_command(T cmd) {
    do_on_modify_command(cmd, typename meta::has_type<T, AvailableCommmands>::type());
  }
private:
  virtual void do_on_modify_command(CommandBase&, std::true_type) = 0;
  virtual void do_on_modify_command(CommandBase& b, std::false_type) {
    std::cout << "Not implemented" << std::endl;
  }

};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  void do_on_modify_command(CommandBase& cmd, std::true_type) {
    std::cout << "Specialized command implementation" << std::endl;
    impl(*static_cast<SomeCommandType*>(&cmd));
  }
  void impl(SomeCommandType cmd) {
    std::cout << "huh!!" << std::endl;
  }

};

int main() {
  CommandA ca;
  Base* b = new Derived;
  b->on_modify_command(ca);
  CommandC cc;
  b->on_modify_command(cc);

  return 0;
}
```

The code is understandably messy, I am sure there must be some better way to do it.

Comment: Interesting way to tackle the issue. Might not fit for what I am looking for. I'm trying to separate the implementations such that one derived class might have a handler for CommandA but not CommandB and another class might have a handler for CommandB and not CommandA and yet another that can handle A and B. I only glanced through this, but it seems this solution ties it that all derivations have to handle the commands in the list?

Comment: @mascoj: You could probably do that with the help of `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast` inside `do_on_modify_command ` function. But for this to work, you will have to make `CommandBase` polymorphic by adding at least one virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood your question exactly, but I came with a solution to the issue of how to allow overloading in the derived classes that will work as "virtual functions" for the template.
I made a small change: the `SpecificCommandA` and `SpecificCommandB` have a common ancestor class `Command`, if in your code they are don't, simply create a `Command` class and have something like `struct SpecificAPrime: Common, SpecificCommandA {};`

First the code:

```
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Command { virtual ~Command() {}; };

struct SpecificCommandA: Command {};
struct SpecificCommandB: Command {};
struct SpecificCommandC: Command {};


struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}; 

    virtual void modify_command(Command &c, std::type_index); // default

    void modify_command(Command &c) {
        modify_command(c, std::type_index(typeid(c)));
    }
};

template<typename Der, typename SpecC> struct Modifier {
    static void execute(Der &d, Command &c) {
        d.modify_command(static_cast<SpecC &>(c)); 
    }
};

struct Derived: Base {
    using Base::modify_command; // <- Because there are overloads
    virtual void modify_command(SpecificCommandB &);
        // Put here the specific code you want for SpecificCommandB.
        // Note that this can be overriden in derived classes

    void modify_command(Command &c, std::type_index ti) override {
        using callable = void (*)(Derived &, Command &);
        const static std::unordered_map<std::type_index, callable> derived_map =
        {
            { std::type_index(typeid(SpecificCommandB)), Modifier<Derived, SpecificCommandB>::execute }
        };
        auto find_result = derived_map.find(ti);
        if(derived_map.end() == find_result) { Base::modify_command(c, ti); }
        else { (*find_result->second)(*this, c); }
    }
};
```

The idea is the following: since now the Commands have a common ancestor, and are polymorphic, dynamic polymorphism can be used instead of templates, including the typeid operator.

Now `modify_command(Command &)` is **not** a template, nor a polymorphic function, what it does is to find the `type_index` of the command and forward it to a polymorphic function.  The implementations of the polymorphic functions `modify_command(Command &, type_index)` have internally a map of the type_index that they know how to modify specifically.  If the given `type_index` is not in the map, they default to the base class implementation, and if the `type_index` is in the map, then call the mapped element, which is just an instantiation of a template function that calls the given specific overload.

In a sense what this does is a polymorphic type switch.

Here's a complete, running example: http://ideone.com/K1Xmdk